# Problemas ao conectar Mysql com asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

Apareceu um pequeno problema, que na minha antiga aplicação funcionava normalmente.

Minha Class do DAL, não está conectando no Mysql. Sendo que todos os parâmetros de conexão, creio eu que esteja correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha DAL que faz a conexão.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Geax1.Model;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace Geax1.DAL
{
   public class VeiculosDAL
   {
    public static void cadastra(_Veiculos obj)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;Database=xpto;User ID=root;Password='';"))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                String InsertVeiculos = ("INSERT INTO tab_veiculo (placa,quilometragem,cor,tipo,ano,chassi,modelo) VALUES(@placa, @cor, @tipo, @ano, @chassi, @modelo)");

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = InsertVeiculos;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placa", obj.Placa1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quilometragem", obj.Quilometragem1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cor", obj.Cor1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", obj.Tipo1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", obj.Ano1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chassi", obj.Chassi1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modelo", obj.Modelo1);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Obs: Meu WAMP está on.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://github.com/brunoocasali/DataRepository
é um repositório para te ajudar a escrever essas classes de conexão com o banco de uma forma beeeeemmmm mais simples, :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tá faltando permissão, por mais que seja o root o usuário:

Execute o seguinte:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Reinicie o WAMP.